# What is wrong with this forward declaration

Tags: c++, qt, forward-declaration

Several times I used the pimple idiom to get a short compilation time. To get a "good" header file I return a pointer of a vector that contains pointer of QPoint (an Qt-object).

Lets have a look at my header file:

```
#ifndef CHEXAGON_H
#define CHEXAGON_H

class QPoint;
class QVector;

class CHexagon
{
public:
    CHexagon(const unsigned int & PosX, const unsigned int & PosY, const unsigned int & Radius);
    QVector * getEdges();
    QPoint * getCenter();
private:
    class Pimple;
    Pimple * pPimple;
};

#endif // CHEXAGON_H
```

Whats wrong with it?

Comment: See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88346/under-which-circumstances-should-i-delete-my-own-question-or-answer/88353#88353

Comment: Ask: my vectors store a type of?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`QVector` isn't a class, it is a class template and can't be declared as you did.

```
template <typename T> QVector;
```

and then using `QVector<QPoint*>` should do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

[Nothing.](http://ideone.com/3aOHk)

What makes you think that something is wrong with it?